# Woocommerce how to get products images of recent orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-theming

The code below re-displays each image without resetting at each foreach loop.

For example it gives:

- product 1 - image1
- product 2 - image1+2
- product 3 - image1+2+3 ...

How can I make sure that the pictures of the past products are not displayed again for the following products?

Expected result:

- product 1 - image 1
- product 2 - image 2
- product 3 - image 3 ...

Thank you in advance, here is my code:

```
    <?php foreach ( $last_order->get_items() as $item ) : ?>
        <?php 
   $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
    $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 50, 50)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
    if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 ){
        $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>' . $item_name;
}
 echo $item_name . $item->get_name();?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have an extra variable called `$item_name` at the end of your `$item_name` variable!  Replace you code with the following code to fix the duplicates:

```php
foreach ($last_order->get_items() as $item) :
  $product   = $item->get_product(); 
  $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array(50, 50));
  if ($product->get_image_id() > 0) {
    $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>'; // You had an extra variable here
  }
  echo $item_name . $item->get_name();
endforeach;
```

Tested and works! Let me know if you were able to get it to work too!

Comment: Thank you very much it works! 

(There is just a double $$ on line 1, but I still managed to correct this detail myself  )

Comment: Great! Yes it was a typo because i tested it on a different variable on my end and i forgot to remove it. I just updated my answer.